# Проблема с парсингом JSON

Tags: php, json

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = array();
 
$mysqli = new mysqli();


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from groupa") or die(mysql_error());
  
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $response["shedule"] = array();
 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $shedule = array();
           $shedule["gid"] = $row["gid"];
            $shedule["id_kurs"] = $row["id_kurs"];
            //$shedule["gname"] = $row["gname"];
        array_push($response["shedule"], $shedule);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
 
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
 
 echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

При раскомментировании строки

```
//$shedule["gname"] = $row["gname"];
```

Перестает выводить вообще что-либо, просто белая страница.

У gname в базе тип varchar

Comment: у тебя отладчик сломался?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как пользоваться отладчиком в браузере?

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev Почему отладчик для php должен работать в браузере?

Comment: если ломается при добавлении поля, то смотрите что у вас в этом поле находится.

Comment: [phpstorm Отладка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/250323/), [nebeans отладка](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging_ru.html) и т.д... Подключил и вперёд...

Comment: @teran брал пример с какого-то сайта, до этого все работало

Comment: спасибо ув. эксперты, проблема оказалась в кодировке.

Comment: В месте с echo json_encode отправляйте и правильный загоглок header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Спасибо, изначально так и стоит, просто ,искав ошибку, переставил в другое место)

Answer (score 0):

Дабы не оставить вопрос без ответа отвечаю:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

[5.4.0  Для options](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) были добавлены константы JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, и JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE.

```
$a = array('<foo>',"'bar'",'"baz"','&blong&', "\xc3\xa9");

echo "Обычно: ",     json_encode($a), "\n";
echo "Тэги: ",       json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG), "\n";
echo "Апострофы: ",  json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_APOS), "\n";
echo "Кавычки: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_QUOT), "\n";
echo "Амперсанты: ", json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_AMP), "\n";
echo "Юникод: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n";
echo "Все: ",        json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n\n";
```

Comment: неправда. это неправильно. если я в `ajax` укажу `dataType: 'json'` то в PHP `header`  даром не сдался....

Comment: К тому же у автора итак установлен данный заголовок и проблема была не в нём.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  1) "неправда. это неправильно" -> Посылать нужный заголовок в таких случаях всегда правильно и правда, потому что  ajax dataType: 'json' указывает на тип данных возвращаемых в callback функцию.И  header('Content-Type: application/json') Ему никак не повредит

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я пользовался Jquery dataType: 'json' + PHP header('Content-Type: application/json'), И все было отлично.Не могу понять где ошибся автор ответа ? Да все правильно изложено.Может приведете ваш вариант ответа ввиде обоснованных довидов ,чтоб смогли оценить ваш ответ .Или вы действительно обсираете людей которых считаете конкурентами :)

Comment: Я решил проблему добавив $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");